# Gulp Chmod Error after trying to overwrite file

Tags: gulp, chmod, fileserver, access-rights

I am trying to overwrite a file on a mac fileserver using:

```
gulp.dest('DESTINATIONPATH')
```

The Error:

```
Error: EACCES, chmod 'FILEPATH'
   at Error (native)
```

The filepath is returning the path to the file that I want to overwrite.

I already tried gulp-chmod, but since that is only applying to the source file that I actually want to copy, it has no effect on the file that I want to overwrite.

As a creator of the file that I want to overwrite, it works from my Mac. But when my colleagues try to overwrite, they get the error.

Answer (score 0):

How about piping the destination?

var gulp = require('gulp');
var chmod = require('gulp-chmod');

```
gulp.task('default', function () {
    return gulp.src('FILEPATH').pipe(chmod(755)).pipe(gulp.dest('DESTINATIONPATH'));
});
```

Comment: in this case I would overwrite the file with its own because FILEPATH and DESTINATIONPATH is the same